# Why does a function $f(x)$ have to be bijective in order to have a $f^{-1}(x)$ (in Euclidean plane)?

Tags: graphing-functions

Yes, the title explains itself. I have no take on this one, or insights for that matter. For example, why isn't it enough for a certain function to be injective to have its $f^{-1}(x)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the matter of the nuances of definitions.

If a function from a domain $A$ to a codomain $B$ is merely a subset of $A\times B$, as in the [Wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#Definition), then the function does not "encode" $B$. You end up with the same set of pairs regardless of whether you view $f$ as a function of $A$ to $B$, or of $A$ to a superset $B'\supset B$, or of $A$ to $f(A)=\{f(a)\mid a\in A\}$. In that sense, you are right, you can invert $f$ as a relation, and the result is a function if and only if $f$ was injective.

On the other hand, it is often argued (and this is how I was taught functions in my youth) that it is necessary for the function to "encode"/specify both its domain and its codomain too. For example (I think this probably comes from [Bourbaki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_function_concept#Notion_of_%22function%22_in_contemporary_set_theory)), a function is defined as a *triplet* $(f,A,B)$, where $f$ is a function in the previous sense, and $A, B$ are the domain and the codomain, respectively. *Then*, the inverse $f^{-1}$ exists, as a function $B\to A$ if and only if both it exists in the previous sense, *and* $f(A)=B$, i.e. $f$ is bijective.

As it turns out, most of the time, even intuitively, we regard the functions as defined in the *second* definition above (certainly not the first definition), or something similar that encodes the codomain. We implicitly assume that the function "knows" its codomain somehow, i.e. the function is not just a set of ordered pairs, but it also "knows" which (potentially larger) set the images belong to. Thus the requirement for $f^{-1}$ to exist is $f$ to be bijective, not merely injective.

Answer (score 2):

Surjectivity is necessary to define $f^{-1}$ over $\mathbb R$, and injectivity is necessary to define the map $f^{-1}$ as a function. In fact if $f$ is not surjective then $\exists x\in \mathbb R$ such that $x\notin f(\mathbb R)$ then $f^{-1}(x)=\emptyset$. If $\exists x_1, x_2$ such that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ then $x_1, x_2\in f^{-1}(f(x_1))$, then it's not generally a funcion.